# Setting media/skin urls to another domain breaks image uploader in wysiwyg editor

Tags: cms

If I set the *"Base skin URL"* and *" Base media URL"* to a domain other than the one used for the *"Base URL"* the image uploader in the WYSIWYG editor breaks.

The *"Media storage"* popup appears and I can select an image using the *"Browse files..."* button but any file I select isn't shown in the list and the *" Upload files"* button does nothing what so ever.

I already checked the JavaScript console and the access/error logs of my server but nothing seems to happen at all.

How can I fix this? Or is this a 'feature' and do I have to disable my custom/cdn URL settings just to be able to upload a new image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a separate domain, you need to take advantage of Store Views. In System > Configuration, the select box in the upper right-hand corner defaults is where you select what Store View you are configuring. The default is `Default Config`, which is applied to all store views and the admin (provided that the specific store view does not override the more general/global setting).

Therefore, if you set the `Base media url` here, that change will be applied to admin AND your store views. I would recommend selecting your store view and making the change there, as that will have no effect on the admin scope and thus it should not break the WYSIWYG editor.